# What tradeoffs are there between internal and external validity?

Tags: research-process, methodology, experiment-design

I was reading through an [article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2912019/#b1-0530278) about research design. The authors gave an example on the relation between internal and external validity which I thought might be an important area of consideration when designing research proposals.

> "A restricted study population (and exclusion criteria) may limit bias
>   and increase the internal validity of the study; however, this
>   approach will limit external validity of the study and, thus, the
>   generalizability of the findings to the practical clinical setting.
>   Conversely, a broadly defined study population and inclusion criteria
>   may be representative of practical clinical practice but may increase
>   bias and reduce the internal validity of the study."

Broadly speaking, what questions can be asked to help decide one should strike a balance between the internal and external validity in our research proposal designs? Is it necessary then to carry out a pilot study first to establish some level of internal validity before moving on to establish external validity in a much bigger and formal follow-up study?

Crosspost: [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Validity/What-tradeoffs-are-there-between-internal-and-external-validity)

Comment: Good question (+1). I think that you would have better chances of getting good answers to such _focused research methodology_ question on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) (you might have some luck on Quora as well, so crossposting was a good idea).

Comment: For anyone tracking, it ended up [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185609/what-tradeoffs-are-there-between-internal-and-external-validity)